# How to I hide and show HTML elements using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to I hide and show HTML elements using JQuery without any special effects?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers all of them helped

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the [`hide()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide) and [`show()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show) methods:

```
$("selector").hide();
$("selector").show();
```

Where "selector" is whatever is appropriate. Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#mybutton").click(function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
<div id="mydiv">
This is some text
</div>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Toggle Div">
```

The [`toggle()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) method just calls `show()` if hidden or `hide()` if its not.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#someElement').show(); //an element with id of someElement

$('.someElement').hide();  //hide elements with class of someElement

$('a').hide(); //hide all anchor elements on the page
```

See:

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show

and

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide

Also, would be a good idea to read up on Selectors:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 3):

**Toggling display:**

```
$('selector').toggle();
```

**Show:**

```
$('selector').show();
```

**Hide:**

```
$('selector').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

$("selector").toggle() switches the selected DOM element(s) between hidden and shown.
$("selector").hide() hides the selected DOM element(s).
$("selector").show() shows the selected DOM element(s).

Truthfully though, I think you could've solved this problem without having to consult stackoverflow. The jquery docs are pretty clear imo!

see [the jQuery online documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) for show, hide and toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Hide element:

```
$('#myElement').hide();
```

Show element:

```
$('#myElement').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide: http://docs.jquery.com/Hide

Show: http://docs.jquery.com/Show