# Removing fadeOut in jQuery search suggestions

Tags: jquery

I have a search suggestion script written in jQuery which uses the jQuery framework file to work. The fadeOut function on line 3 is used for hiding the content when there is no text in the search box. However, I do not like the fade function. My question is; How can I removed the fade effect but still make the contents disappear?

I have posted a copy of my code here:

```
function lookup(inputString){
if (inputString.length==0){
$('#suggestions').fadeOut();
} else{
$.post("suggestions.php",{
queryString: "" + inputString + ""
}, function(data){
$('#suggestions').html(data);
});
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, Callum

Comment: Have you done any research before? [`jquery hide element`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+hide+element) yields [http://api.jquery.com/hide/](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I hide and show HTML elements using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073884/how-to-i-hide-and-show-html-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slideUp(), or hide() to "remove" the element. You can also use toggle() which will hide or show based on the current display.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`hide();`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$('#suggestions').hide();
```